# new line JLabel using java swing

Tags: java, html

I'm creating a GUI for a school project app in java, where we are basically trying to output the scores of the hockey games (being read from files), and output them onto screen in a Label, like so:

```
Boston Bruins 1  
Washington Capitals 2

Dallas Stars 2  
St. Louis Blues 1
```

however, on my panel, it is being outputted like this:

```
Boston Bruins 1 Washington Capitals 2 Dallas Stars 2 St. Louis Blues 1
```

on my file, it is formatted like so:

```
Boston Bruins
1
Washington Capitals
2
```

here's my code:

```
for (int m = 0; m < 6; m++) {
            
    JLabel l = new JLabel(nhlAug6[m].getTeamName() + nhlAug6[m].getScores() + "</p></html>");
    
    if (m % 2 != 0) {
       JLabel moderator = new JLabel("<html> <br/> </html>");
       showNhlP.add(moderator);
    } 

    l.setBounds(100, 500, 300, 50);
    showNhlP.add(l);
```

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Please edit your question to provide some sample data. What does the file look like? Also, provide a [mcve]. In other words, provide working code that we can just copy, paste, and run, but not all the code.

Comment: Have you tried using setText() method? Provide how you fetched nhlAug6 array.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a `JLabel` collapses any newline encountered, if I remember correctly.

But you can prefix your string with the text `<html>`, which causes the label text to accept HTML code (probably just a subset of it).

Now you can replace your newlines with `<br>`, and it'll work.

```java
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setText("<html>A line<br>and another line");
```

Comment: I did try this, using this code `JLabel l = new JLabel();
l.setText("<html>" + nhlAug6[m].getTeamName()  + " " + nhlAug6[m].getScores() + " <br> </html>")`; it still didn't work unfortunately

Comment: @Gianluca Well, you have only used a `<br>` at the end of your text. That doesn't make a good test case. I have edited the answer, you should try the code I put there.

Comment: I appreciate the help, just saw the code. works good, but what's weird is it doesn't work when I put nhlAug6[m].getScores() in there

Comment: Well, if `nhlAug6[m].getScores()` return a string with newlines in it, you must replace them with `<br>`.